# Excel Macro: Removing the titles and only copying the items

Tags: excel, copy, paste, vba

So I know how to copy the values and paste it to another sheet and also removing the blank cells but how do you remove the titles (the ID, ITEM, ITEM NUMBER) so that when I paste the items on to another sheet it won't have multiple titles

[image]

Comment: Are the title always have the some range every 10 cells fill?

Comment: @Never_Mind no it's not always 10

Comment: Post your existing code  -easier to add a couple of lines than to invent a whole procedure...

Answer (score 0):

I recently developed a function that gets the 'header' of a file.  It was written for the csv module, but I think could be quickly reworked to deal with Excel.  You will also need to deal with the fact that there are multiple headers.  I have a added a `while` statement to deal with this.  Here is the function:

```
def getHeader(file):
   import csv
   headername = None
   charList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '+', '+', "'", '"', '{', '}', '[', ']', '?', '.', ',', '<', '>', '/', '~', '`', '-', '_']
   rowcount = 0
   headercsv = open(file, 'r', newline = '')
   headerreader = csv.reader(headercsv, delimiter = ',')
   while rowcount < 5:
      for row in headerreader:
          rowcount += 1
          if row[0][0] in charList and row[1][0] in charList:
              headername = row
      headercsv.close()
   return headername
```

I call it by setting a variable equal to it: `thisHeader = getHeader('filename')`

Then I implement it in code by doing (I'm using CSV module as an example- its what I'm familiar with):

```
for row in csvreader:
    if row == thisHeader:
        continue
    else:
        <get the data>
```

Additionally, you can also use `thisHeader` to write the first row in your Excel spreadsheet, so you don't need to keep dealing with it.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you already have a working macro doing the other stuff. I would check column `A` to see if it's numeric and VBA has a `IsNumeric` function.